# counting records from a grouped query with additional criteria

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table of reports that has these relevant fields:

```
user_id (int 11)
submitted_date (datetime)
approved_flag (shortint 1)
```

There are multiple rows per `user_id`, some with `approved_flag` = 0 and some with `approved_flag` = 1 and each with a unique `submitted_date`.

I need to get a count of the approved and unapproved reports.  But I only want to count the most recent submitted report per user (most recent `submitted_date`), regardless of `approved_flag`.

So, if there was 4 records like this:

```
    user_id, submitted_date, approved_flag
    1, 2009-04-01 01:00, 1
    1, 2009-04-01 02:00, 0
    1, 2009-04-01 03:00, 1 (using this record)
    2, 2009-04-02 01:00, 1 (using this record)
```

the count would be 2 approved and no unapproved, and if we had

```
    user_id, submitted_date, approved_flag
    1, 2009-04-01 01:00, 1
    1, 2009-04-01 02:00, 0
    1, 2009-04-01 03:00, 0 (using this record)
    2, 2009-04-02 01:00, 0
    2, 2009-04-02 02:00, 1 (using this record)
```

the count would be 1 approved (user id 2) and 1 unapproved (user id 1).

To summarize one more time because it is not easy to describe:  I want the total number of unique users in the table (regardless of # rows per user) and I want it broken down in to 'approved' and 'not approved' based on the `approved_flag` of the most recent report per user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: am I understanding correctly that you would never have a count higher than one (per user)? and that your approved + unapproved counts would never be higher than one (per user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT approved_flag, COUNT(*)
FROM 
  Table t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, submitted_date = MAX(submitted_date)
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) latest ON latest.user_id = t.user_id
              AND latest.submitted_date = t.submitted_date
GROUP BY approved_flag
```

Comment: What happened to the user ID?

Comment: Thanks Lieven, that gives me exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Jonathan, the user_id was only required in the inner select to get the last submitted date per user_id and to be able to join with the outer select. For the end result, there was no user_id required.

Answer (score 1):

Can think of two ways to do this.  The first is perhaps the most readable, search for the last submitted_date per user, and then display the approval with that timestamp:

```
select a.user_id, a.submitted_date, a.approved_flag
from approvals a
inner join (
    select user_id, maxdt = max(submitted_date)
    from approvals
    group by user_id
) latest on latest.user_id = a.user_id 
    and latest.maxdt = a.submitted_date
```

The second is to join the table on it's future rows for the same user, and specify in the where clause that these don't exist. This gives you the latest entry for each user:

```
select cur.user_id, cur.submitted_date, cur.approved_flag
from approvals cur
left join approvals next
    on next.user_id = cur.user_id
    and next.submitted_date > cur.submitted_date
where next.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, approved_flag, COUNT(*)
FROM reports 
WHERE NOW() - submitted_date < 'whatever'
GROUP BY user_id, approved_flag
```

Hope it works..

Comment: Can you have a GROUP BY before WHERE?

Comment: uhh i don't have the exact sql syntax in mind but it seems you're right i'll correct it

Comment: Hmm, not sure what 'whatever' is supposed to be because I want the most recent report for each user, and I don't think you can have a 'group by' clause before a 'where' clause (at least my MySQL complains), and even then, this appears to give me duplicate results if the user has an approved and an unapproved result (I only want the most recent result, approved or unapproved), thanks for trying!